# Highlight current menu for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I've created a custom post type and rather than using the default listing, add and edit menus I've created my own, like this:

```
add_action('admin_menu','wp_rss_multi_importer_menu');

function wp_rss_multi_importer_menu () {

    add_menu_page(__('Overview'), __('RSS Multi Importer'), 'manage_options', 'wprssmi', 'wp_rss_multi_importer_intro_page', '', '150'); 

    add_submenu_page('wprssmi', 'Instructions', 'Instructions','manage_options', 'wprssmi', 'wp_rss_multi_importer_intro_page', '', '');

    add_submenu_page( 'wprssmi', 'Feed List', 'Feed List', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?post_type=rssmi_feed', '' );

    add_submenu_page( 'wprssmi', 'Add a Feed', 'Add a Feed', 'edit_posts', 'post-new.php?post_type=rssmi_feed', '' );


}
```

This works fine except when I edit an entry because the menu doesn't stay open, as shown here

http://www.screencast.com/t/vHLeeu0H

Is there a way to make it so when I click to edit an entry the menu stays open (like it does when you're editing a regular post)?

Answer (score 0):

ok...here's how it's done

```
global $parent_file;
$parent_file = 'wprssmi';
```